# Receiving XML file from http in C

Tags: c, xml, http, transfer

I need to somehow enable XML file transfer in the way that some machine, which generates a XML file sends the XML file through HTTP to another client. This other client would be based on C, receive the XML file and process it.

Is this possible in any way? I only found results for sending XML files to a HTTP server using some URL. I guess I'd have to implement my own HTTP server in my C application? Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use http so send your file (no matter if it's XML or anything else), the receiving computer must have some kind of a http server.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Ok I guess there is no way of going around it then. Thanks, there are lots of documentations of http servers on the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can use libcurl

here is a http POST example: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html

on the receiving computer has to be a listening socket. here is a socket example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/586000/Networking-and-Socket-programming-tutorial-in-C

this socket takes the incoming data for later processing...

Comment: Sounds good, was already thinking about doing it this way but thought it would be easier, thanks!